# Showing 3d spikes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]

I am pretty new to QGIS and was hoping some one could point me on how to put 3d spikes on to my 2d map? I have lat, long data and a value (lets say population] for each of the record. I am trying to map the population as a 3d spike.

Comment: That map isn't 2D. In fact it's not even a map. What is wrong with simply colouring your map?

Comment: I got this image off internet.I am having a normal 2d layer -just trying to put vertical spike (3d) instead of a point to show the population

Comment: I am Environmentist, how can I use above application in my field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Qgis2threejs** would be possible solution.

Open your modules manager, click "all" and find Qgis2threejs. Install it and a button of this module should appear on tools panel.

[image]

Next, prepare your point layer. It should contain a decimal field with values you want spikes to have heights.

Place point layer in a window with an extent you want to see further.

Open Qgis2threejs:

1. Put a tick on a "Flat Plane"
2. Put a tick on point layer
3. Double click on a point layer and set your properties:

   - Object type: Cone
   - Style - Height: under "Expression" open combobox and select field containing your decimal values.

[image]

You can also increase height with math expressions. Radius and other parameters also can be set. Here is a brief look:

[image]

Hope it helps!